# Errors when building DSpace 6.3 Mirage2 theme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dspace

I am trying to install DSpace 6.3 on an Amazon LightSail instance running Ubuntu 18.04. When running the `mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true` command, I get the following error, which I am unable to resolve using suggestions available in forums online.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize (default) on project xmlui-mirage2: Execution default of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize failed: Java returned: 137 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize (default) on project xmlui-mirage2: Execution default of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize failed: Java returned: 137
```

Detailed debug output is at https://pastebin.com/vgbyp6Cc.

I have done the following before running the `mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true` command, as per instructions from https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace:

- sudo apt install default-jdk
- sudo apt install maven
- sudo apt install ant
- sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
- cd /etc/postgresql/10/main
- sudo cp postgresql.conf postgresql.conf.bak
- Edit postgresql.conf to uncomment the line “listen_addresses = ‘localhost’”
- sudo cp pg_hba.conf pg_hba.conf.bak
- Edit pg_hba.conf and add the following line before any other uncommented line: “host dspace dspace 127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 md5”
- sudo systemctl restart postgresql
- sudo groupadd tomcat
- sudo useradd -M -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
- cd /opt
- sudo wget http://us.mirrors.quenda.co/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.22/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz
- sudo mkdir tomcat
- sudo tar xvfz apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
- sudo rm /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.22.tar.gz
- sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat
- sudo chmod -R g+r /opt/tomcat/conf
- sudo chmod g+x /opt/tomcat/conf
- Create /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service with suggested contents
- sudo systemctl daemon-reload
- sudo systemctl start tomcat
- sudo systemctl status tomcat
- sudo cp /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml.bak
  Edit /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml to add the following line before the end of the  block: URIEncoding="UTF-8"
- sudo wget https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases/download/dspace-6.3/dspace-6.3-release.tar.gz
- sudo tar xvfz dspace-6.3-release.tar.gz
- sudo rm /opt/dspace-6.3-release.tar.gz
- sudo mv /opt/dspace-6.3-release /opt/dspace-source
- sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /opt/dspace-source
- sudo -u postgres createuser --username=postgres --no-superuser --pwprompt dspace
- sudo -u postgres createdb --username=postgres --owner=dspace --encoding=UNICODE dspace
- sudo -u postgres psql --username=postgres dspace -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;"
- sudo cp /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/local.cfg.EXAMPLE /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/local.cfg
- sudo chown tomcat:tomcat /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/local.cfg
- Edit /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/local.cfg
- sudo mkdir /opt/dspace
- sudo chown tomcat:tomcat /opt/dspace
- sudo cp /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/xmlui.xconf /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/xmlui.xconf.bak
- Edit the file /opt/dspace-source/dspace/config/xmlui.xconf to change the line “” to read “”
- cd /opt/dspace-source
- sudo -u tomcat mvn package -Dmirage2.on=true

Upon encountering the error, I've tried the following as per recommendations online:

- Apply the following patch to the /opt/dspace-source/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/pom.xml file: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/pull/2315/files#diff-5576a54a7c1a9188bf7f34514ce72078
- sudo -u tomcat git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/

None of these seem to be able to resolve the issue.

**UPDATE**

Increasing the memory from 512MB to 1GB as suggested seems to have mostly solved the issue. But I'm still getting a few of the same error messages reported at https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-4115 though. The DSpace application, however, appears to load fine despite these errors.

```
bower bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.0 invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain font, image, audio, or video files
bower bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.0 invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain font, image, audio, or video files
bower bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.0 invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain font, image, audio, or video files
bower bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.0 invalid-meta The "main" field cannot contain font, image, audio, or video files
bower bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.0 invalid-meta The "main" field has to contain only 1 file per filetype; found multiple .js files: ["assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js","assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"]
```

Comment: what is your jdk version?

Comment: The default-jdk package initially installed JDK v11, but I also tried uninstalling this and installing the openjdk-8-jdk package, which installed JDK v8. I have the same issue with both.

Comment: The following PR might be helpful: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/pull/2315

Comment: @terrywb - Yup, already tried this, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

137=128+9, which means some other process has sent you a signal 9, which is SIGKILL. can it be a memory issue?

As Dspace documentation say about a minimal instalation (https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/User+FAQ#UserFAQ-WhatsortofhardwaredoesDSpacerequire?Whataboutsizingtheserver?HowmuchdiskspacedoIneed?) I would need:

2-3 GB of Random Access Memory (RAM)

- 1GB for Tomcat (e.g. "TOMCAT_OPTS=-server -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")
- 1GB for Database (PostgreSQL or Oracle).
- Keep in mind your Operating System also needs some memory to function. So, while DSpace may only need ~2GB of memory, you should ensure the computer itself has at least 3-4GB of RAM available overall.
- 20 GB of Storage (or roughly enough storage for all the files you wish to store in DSpace)

Comment: That could be likely. The Amazon LightSail instance has only 512MB memory. Are there any minimum memory requirements to run DSpace? Will try increasing the memory temporarily to see if it helps.

Comment: Edited answer to include minimun requirements

Comment: Note that "some other process" could be the OOM Killer kernel thread that kills demanding processes when the kernel is desperate to free some memory.

OTOH note also that the problem occurs while *building* DSpace, so the memory requirements for Tomcat, DBMS, etc. are irrelevant.