# I've got error when trying to rebuild dspace

Tags: dspace

I am trying to rebuild dspace in order to update a language in the site, but I've got an error when run `mvn -U clean package -Dmirage2.on=true`. This is similar to an error found at [Errors when building DSpace 6.3 Mirage2 theme on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194762/errors-when-building-dspace-6-3-mirage2-theme-on-ubuntu-18-04), but it's not the same.
Part of error message is:

```
[INFO] Building DSpace Parent Project 6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ dspace-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ dspace-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ dspace-parent ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DSpace Addon Modules 6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ modules ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ modules ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ modules ---
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DSpace Kernel :: Additions and Local Customizations 6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/dspace/dspace-api-lang/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/dspace/dspace-api-lang/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.6 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ additions ---
[INFO] Deleting /dspace/dspace-source/dspace/modules/additions/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ additions ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ additions ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ additions ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ additions ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /dspace/dspace-source/dspace/modules/additions/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ additions ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ additions ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ additions ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ additions ---
[INFO] Building jar: /dspace/dspace-source/dspace/modules/additions/target/additions-6.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DSpace XML-UI Mirage2 Theme :: Local Customisations 6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:sass/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/compass-core/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:compass-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-core/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer rubygems:sass/maven-metadata.xml from http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of rubygems-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata rubygems:sass/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rake/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/rake/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/rake/maven-metadata.xml (322 B at 0.7 KB/sec)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:rake/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rake/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/multi_json/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/multi_json/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:multi_json/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/multi_json/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-import-once/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/compass-import-once/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:compass-import-once/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-import-once/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer rubygems:sass/maven-metadata.xml from http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of rubygems-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata rubygems:sass/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/chunky_png/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/chunky_png/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:chunky_png/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/chunky_png/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-fsevent/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/rb-fsevent/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:rb-fsevent/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-fsevent/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-inotify/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/rb-inotify/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:rb-inotify/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-inotify/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
Downloading: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata rubygems:ffi/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer rubygems:rake/maven-metadata.xml from http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of rubygems-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata rubygems:rake/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rake/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer rubygems:ffi/maven-metadata.xml from http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of rubygems-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata rubygems:ffi/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer rubygems:ffi/maven-metadata.xml from http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of rubygems-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata rubygems:ffi/maven-metadata.xml from/to rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ xmlui-mirage2 ---
[INFO] Deleting /dspace/dspace-source/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-java) @ xmlui-mirage2 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ xmlui-mirage2 ---
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:sass' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:compass-core: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:compass-core' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-core/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:compass-core: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:sass' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:multi_json: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:multi_json' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/multi_json/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:multi_json: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:compass-import-once: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:compass-import-once' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/compass-import-once/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:compass-import-once: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:sass' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/sass/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:sass: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:chunky_png: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:chunky_png' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/chunky_png/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:chunky_png: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:rb-fsevent: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:rb-fsevent' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-fsevent/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:rb-fsevent: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:rb-inotify: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:rb-inotify' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/rb-inotify/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:rb-inotify: checking for updates from central
[INFO] artifact rubygems:ffi: checking for updates from rubygems-release
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact rubygems:ffi' could not be retrieved from repository: rubygems-release due to an error: Failed to transfer file: http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases/rubygems/ffi/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[INFO] artifact rubygems:ffi: checking for updates from central
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ xmlui-mirage2 ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] PATH=/home/wesinalves/bin:/home/wesinalves/.local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
     [echo] GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global
     [echo] GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
     [echo] mirage2.deps.included=true
     [echo] grunt.color.scheme=classic_mirage_color_scheme
     [echo] grunt.environment=prod
     [echo] source=/dspace/dspace-source/dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes/
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize (default) @ xmlui-mirage2 ---
[INFO] Successfully installed sass-3.3.14
[INFO]     Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
[INFO] Successfully installed compass-1.0.1
[INFO] Successfully installed compass-core-1.0.3
[INFO] Successfully installed multi_json-1.14.1
[INFO] Successfully installed compass-import-once-1.0.5
[INFO] Successfully installed chunky_png-1.3.11
[INFO] Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.3
[WARNING] ERROR:  Error installing /home/wesinalves/.m2/repository/rubygems/rb-inotify/0.10.0/rb-inotify-0.10.0.gem:
[WARNING]       rb-inotify requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
[INFO] Successfully installed ffi-1.11.3-java
[INFO] 8 gems installed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] DSpace Parent Project .............................. SUCCESS [  0.419 s]
[INFO] DSpace Addon Modules ............................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] DSpace Kernel :: Additions and Local Customizations  SUCCESS [  4.105 s]
[INFO] DSpace XML-UI Mirage2 Theme :: Local Customisations  FAILURE [ 22.534 s]
[INFO] DSpace XML-UI (Manakin) :: Local Customizations .... SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace JSP-UI :: Local Customizations .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace RDF :: Local Customizations ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace REST :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SWORD :: Local Customizations ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SWORD v2 :: Local Customizations ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SOLR :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace OAI-PMH :: Local Customizations ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace Assembly and Configuration .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.354 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-19T10:09:32-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/387M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize (default) on project xmlui-mirage2: Execution default of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize failed: Java returned: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize (default) on project xmlui-mirage2: Execution default of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize failed: Java returned: 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal de.saumya.mojo:gem-maven-plugin:1.0.6:initialize failed: Java returned: 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: Java returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:87)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.script.AntLauncher.doExecute(AntLauncher.java:107)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.script.AntLauncher.executeScript(AntLauncher.java:174)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.script.AntLauncher.executeScript(AntLauncher.java:159)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.script.AntLauncher.executeScript(AntLauncher.java:153)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.script.Script.execute(Script.java:81)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.gems.GemsInstaller.installGems(GemsInstaller.java:196)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.gems.GemsInstaller.installGems(GemsInstaller.java:114)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.gems.GemsInstaller.installGems(GemsInstaller.java:102)
        at de.saumya.mojo.ruby.gems.GemsInstaller.installPom(GemsInstaller.java:61)
        at de.saumya.mojo.gem.AbstractGemMojo.executeJRuby(AbstractGemMojo.java:356)
        at de.saumya.mojo.jruby.AbstractJRubyMojo.execute(AbstractJRubyMojo.java:298)
        at de.saumya.mojo.gem.AbstractGemMojo.execute(AbstractGemMojo.java:222)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :xmlui-mirage2
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, DSPACE 6.0, openjdk version "1.8.0_232", and tomcat8.

Please, can you help me to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade "make" to an upper version (3.2 or greater)

Comment: it is 4.1 version. Any other suggestion?